# Extract non numerical values from a numeric column in databricks

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have received a large database where the id column which should be numeric value (currently stored as string) has some non numeric values. I wanted to extract all such cases where the column has non numeric values. I am using DataBricks.

I tried this but couldn't find `REGEXP_LIKE` function

```
SELECT customer FROM customer_check
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (customer, '^[a-zA-Z]*$')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rlike` instead:

```
WHERE customer RLIKE '[^0-9]')
```

This will find any customer that has a character that is not a number.  If numbers can be decimals or negative, you can extend the regular expression.

Comment: Will it work with negative numeric values?